# What does comma do while using cin in c++

Tags: c++

I was practicing practicing some programming and by mistake wrote the following line of code :

```
int a,b;
cin>>a,b;
```

Can anybody explain what the comma does here and why doesn't the compiler show any error.

Comment: Comma operator: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other

Answer (score 1):

It means that the whole expression has the value b.

But because b is not initialised the behaviour of your code is undefined!

Modern compilers can warm you of this.